# Is the way I moved my fish to a new tank ok?

Tags: aquarium

Yesterday I got a new tank, I upgraded from a standard 10 gallon tank to a 29 gallon. The ten gallon was over populated so I decided to try and move my fish over as soon as I could. The ten gallon tank had sand as substrate that was a pain to clean so I decided to get a more coarse gravel. I had an aqueon 10 quiet flow filter, the new tank came with the same filter but bigger (rated for up to 30 gallons). Because I removed the original sand I figured it would be smart to run both the new and old filter because of all the bacteria in the old one. I moved all the decorations to the new tank. I took out about 7-8 gallons from the 10 gallon tank to put into the 29 gallon, the rest of the water got too gross from moving stuff, and I filled it the rest of the way up. I slowly moved the fish over from the 10 to the 29, making sure to properly acclimated them first. Now today some of my fish seem “out of it” my red tail shark is very resilient and seems totally fine, but my sword tails are all in the top left corner of the tank hiding near the filter. Is this normal for the circumstances? Is it ok that I moved the fish over in this manor?[image]

Comment: They seem to be getting air from the surface. Turn on an airpump and see if the behavior changes. Did you measure your water values (after such a major change you should check for amonia once, maybe even twice a day since it can rise within hours, even though it's unlikely after your precautions)? If the filter doesn't work (not in the mechanical, but biological sense), high levels of nitrite or even amonia can lead to behavioral issues.

Comment: I already had an air pump so I don’t think that was the problem. Today they seem much better so I think they just needed some time to adjust to the new tank. I’ll bring a sample of my water to the local pet store to get it tested because I don’t actually have an ammonia test kit. I will invest in one soon. Thanks for the advice

Comment: So you had both the old and the new filter running at the same time in your new tank? In that case I believe you did the move as good as you could.